# how do i get my customer records to still appear in the table beyond the 5 days advance period

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query that pull out all customers records I will need to call within the next 5 days in the where clause as:

```
Remind to call =< DATEADD(DD,5,GETDATE() and
Remind to call >= GETDATE()
```

The way i want it to work is that i want all customers records that i need to call 5 days in advance from GETDATE(). Once it has entered the table, it needs to stay in the table until users enters a date for the 'Confirmstart' field  on web application.

What happens is my query displays the data as it should except it removes the customers record after the 5 days where i want the records to remain until the user has entered a date  for the 'ConfirmStart' field

For example - Lets say todays date is 03/08/2016 where I want to pull out the customers i need to call within the next 5 days, therefore in my where clause i wrote:

```
<Remind to call =< DATEADD(DD,5,GETDATE() and
<Remind to call >= GETDATE()
```

The Dateadd should pull out records up to 08/08/2016. t also say record iD called 'CR1' that has a RemindToCall date 08/08/2013 meet this criteria.

The 'CR1' record appears in the table which is great. However when GETDATE() reaches the 9/08/2016, the 'CR1' record disappears from the table when i want it to still remain in that table  until the 'ConfirmedStart' date is entered.

How do i get my customer records to still appear in the table beyond the 5 days advance period even though i need the records to appear 5 days in advance?

**Further Information:**
To elaborate on my above example - here is the SQL code that for the 'CR1' record but instead of it being named 'CR1' in this live example its CoS ID record called'1232' - everything else remains the same:

> SELECT 
>     CoSID,
>     SurName,
>     FirstName,
>     EmailAddress,
>     CONVERT (varchar,UKAddressDeadline,103) as UKAddressDeadline,
>     CONVERT (varchar,PlacementStart,103) as PlacementStart, 
>     CONVERT (varchar,PlacementEnd,103) as PlacementEnd,
>     CONVERT (varchar,RemindToCall,103) as RemindToCall,
>     ExtReference,
>     HostOrgName,
>     UKEndorsement,
>     PaymentUKBA
>
> FROM
>     dbo.tbl_CoS
>
> WHERE
>
> RemindToCall between CAST('2016-08-03' AS DATE) and DateAdd(DD,+5, CAST('2016-08-03' AS DATE))  AND
>
> (CoSNotRequired is null and
>     AppWithdrawn = 0 and
>     CoSWithdrawn = 0 and
>     VisaRejected = 0 and
>     UKAddressDeadline is not null AND
>     ConfirmedStart is NULL OR
>     UKEndorsement is NULL)

[SQL RESULT of above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8pMJ.jpg)

I hope this extra information/details help you.

Thanks people :D

Comment: just give a sample data and a sample result.

Comment: First - you are only running a select, you aren't loading the data into another table that can remember who has been called or not. Is there a suitable 'I called' field in the existing table that you are selecting from? If not you need to load into a new table with Insert. Anyone can help with your question if you just supply enough information.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the Confirmstart is null when no value are entered.

Add that to your where clause

```
WHERE 
(
  (
    [Remind to call] =< DATEADD(DD,5,GETDATE() and
    [Remind to call] >= GETDATE()
  )
  OR 
  (
    Confirmstart IS NULL
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
([Remind to call] =< DATEADD(DD,5,GETDATE() and
[Remind to call] > CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)) or
ConfirmStart is Null
```

In other words, you have to pass in the second line not `GetDate()`, but `08/08/2016 00:00:00`